# javascript чтение из txt файла

Tags: javascript

Нужно считать данные их txt файла на javascript, откуда-бы не взял пример, у меня не работает:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
      f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.route&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>
</script>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  <output id="list"></output>
</body>
</html>
```

И даже тут он работает, а у меня ругается:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Никак не могу понять, может кто-нибудь подскажет.

Comment: в сниппете все работает. Проблема определенно в твоем коде. Скорее всего когда ты вызываешь _document.getElementById('files')_ такого элемента еще нет

Comment: Добавьте свой `JavaScript`-код внутрь `$(document).ready(function() {/*сюда*/}` либо сюда, если нет jQuery: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){/*сюда*/}`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, судя по предоставленному коду автор не используется jQuery, следовательно не может сделать `$(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Есть подозрения, что у Вас `JavaScript` выполняется раньше, чем подгрузился `HTML` и построено `DOM`-дерево. Добавьте свой `JavaScript`-код внутрь блока:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){/*JS-код*/}
```

такой код аналогичен коду `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {/*JS-код*/}
```

Код , включенный внутри этого блока будет работать только после того , как объектная модель страницы документа (DOM) будет готова для выполнения `JavaScript`-кода.

Вот таким должен стать Ваш код:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (',f.type || 'n/a',') - ',
        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
        f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.route&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>
</script>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  <output id="list"></output>
</body>

</html>
```

[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) – браузер полностью загрузил `HTML`, и построил `DOM`-дерево.